# How to unit test bloc with network relative repostitory?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, bloc

I create a bloc call `Authentication`. This bloc emit two state call `Autenticated` and `UnAuthenticated` base on `AuthenticationRepository` which dependency injected into bloc.

Then I tring to create a mocked `MockAuthenticationRepository` for unit test but I got two different state so I have to create two different version of repository like `MockAutenticatedAuthenticationRepository` and `MockUnAuthenticatedAuthenticationRepository` to test these two case.

But maybe there is a another bloc emit 5 or 6 state base on repository then i have to create 5 to 6 mocked repository for it. This sound not terribly wrong because one bloc shondn't growing unlimit. But I still looking for better way to solve this. Anyone got better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the package mocktail (https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail) to set up the correct behavior of the repository.
It´s also a good idea to use the package bloc_test (https://pub.dev/packages/bloc_test) to implement bloc unit tests.

```
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

class MockAutenticatedAuthenticationRepository extends Mock implements AutenticatedAuthenticationRepository {};

void main() {
  late MockAutenticatedAuthenticationRepository authMock;
  late AuthBloc bloc;

  setUp(() {
    authMock = MockAutenticatedAuthenticationRepository();
    bloc = AuthBloc(auchRepository: authMock);
  });


 blocTest(
      'should emit [AuthLoadingState, AuthSuccessState] when login data is correct',
      build: () {
        when(() => authMock.doAuth(any())).thenAnswer((_) async => true);
        return bloc;
      },
      act: (dynamic b) => b.add(AuthEvent.login("username","password")),
      expect: () => [AuthState.loading(), AuthState.success()],
    );

   blocTest(
      'should emit [AuthLoadingState, AuthFailureState] when login data is incorrect',
      build: () {
        when(() => authMock.doAuth(any())).thenAnswer((_) async => false);
        return bloc;
      },
      act: (dynamic b) => b.add(AuthEvent.login("username","wrong password")),
      expect: () => [AuthState.loading(), AuthState.failure()],
    );
}
```

You have to adapt the method calls and so on, because i don´t have your example code. But i think that should help you solving your problem.

Comment: This is right and my approach is wrong. I should mock `AuthenticationRepository ` directly instead of create more fake version of `AuthenticationRepository` then mock stuff inside.